# many_to_many batch insert/update

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to save struct with many_to_many relationship.

Let's say I have `user` and `role` schema created in following way:

*migration:*

```
def change do
 create table(:users) do
   add :email, :string
   add :username, :string
 end

 create table(:roles) do
   add :name, :string, null: false
 end

 create table(:users_roles, primary_key: false) do
  add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
  add :role_id, references(:roles, on_delete: :delete_all)
 end

 create unique_index(:users, [:email, :username]
 create unique_index(:roles, [:name])
 create unique_index(:users_roles, [:user_id, :role_id])
end
```

*user schema:*

```
schema "users" do
  field :email, :string
  field :username, :string
  many_to_many :roles, TimesheetServer.Role, join_through: "users_roles"
 end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
   struct
    |> cast(params, [:email, :username])
    |> validate_required([:email, :username])
  end
end
```

*role schema:*

```
schema "roles" do
     field :name, :string
     many_to_many :users, TimesheetServer.User, join_through: "users_roles"
   end

   def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
     |> cast(params, [:name])
     |> validate_required([:name])
   end
 end
```

There is no problem with association when it comes to associating a single role with a user. However, when it comes to associating multiple roles in one request I came up only with the following solution:

update user endpoint: `/api/users/{user_id}`

*request body:*

```
{
  "roles": [
    {"id": 10},
    {"id": 2},
    {"id": 1}
  ]
}
```

*user changeset:*

```
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
      |> cast(params, [:email, :username])
      |> validate_required([:email, :username])
      |> put_assoc(:roles, cast_roles(params))
  end

  defp cast_roles(params) do
    %{"roles" => roles} = params
    Enum.map(roles, fn role -> get_role(role) end)
  end

  defp get_role(role) do
    %{"id" => id} = role
    Repo.get!(Role, id)
  end
```

That does work, the association is updated. What I am worried about is that I have to iterate over roles and do DB request for each of them. Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I usually create a module/schema for `users_roles` and then adding an association becomes just `Repo.insert %UserRole{user_id: user_id, role_id: role_id}` (after appropriate validations, if needed).

Comment: So, in that case I would just create multiple `%UserRole` structs and then do `Repo.insert_all`, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module/schema for the association which points to the `users_roles` table and then just insert a `%UserRole{}` struct to create an association between a `User` and a `Role`. This way you can also use `Repo.insert_all` to do bulk inserts.

```
defmodule MyApp.UserRole do
  ...
  schema "users_roles" do
    belongs_to :user, User
    belongs_to :role, Role
  end
end
```

```
Repo.insert! %MyApp.UserRole{user_id: 123, role_id: 456}
```

or

```
Repo.insert_all! MyApp.UserRole, [%{user_id: 1, role_id: 1},
                                  %{user_id: 2, role_id: 1},
                                  %{user_id: 2, role_id: 2}]
```

Comment: It won't work without adding `@primary_key false` just before `users_roles` schema definition. Otherwise, it throws:  `** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column "id" of relation "users_roles" does not exist`